# Create nested property from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume I have an empty object like so:

```
var object = {};
```

How can I add a property with a nested object using variables?  E.g.:

```
<span id='obj1'>person</span>
<span id='nestedObj'>name</span>

var obj1 = $( '#obj1' ).text();
var nestedObj = $( '#nestedObj' ).text();
function (obj1, nestedObj) {
    //Trying to simulate object.person.nestedObj
    object[obj1][nestedObj] = 'someone';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure object[obj1] is valid first:

```
    object[obj1] = object[obj1] || {};
    object[obj1][nestedObj] = 'someone'
```

This basically says "If object[obj1]" is undefined, make it an object, otherwise assign it to itself.

Answer (score 0):

`object[obj1]` has to be initialized:

```
var obj1 = $( '#obj1' ).text();
var nestedObj = $( '#nestedObj' ).text();

if(!object[obj1]) {
    object[obj1] = {};
}

object[obj1][nestedObj] = 'someone';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function O(key, val) {
    var o = {};
    o[key] = val;
    return o;
}

function f(obj1, nestedObj) {
    $.extend(true, object, O(obj1, O(nestedObj, 'someone')));
}
```